# Как мне отслеживать выполнение всех JS на странице?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Страница сайта. На ней расположена листалка, написанная на JS. С помощью JQ я вмешиваюсь в верстку этой листалки и добавляю свои элементы. При листании листалка обновляется, и все мои украшения слетают.

Я всучил в метод листания свою функцию, и она исправно выполняется после листания, НО эта листалка не 1 раз обновляется, она:

- обновляется;
- листается;
- выполняет мою функцию;
- снова обновляется (удаляя всё, что я сделал своей функцией в предыдущем пункте)

**Вопрос:** как мне отслеживать, что все JS выполнены на странице, чтобы выполнить свою функцию?

Страница не обновляется, поэтому `$(document).ready` не прокатывает.

Comment: как насчет внести изменения в саму листалку?

Comment: Это не тот случай, когда надо просто использовать setTimeout(). Извините, если невнимательно вопрос прочитал.

Comment: мне в голову приходит только идея использования `[.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)`

Comment: Можно ссылку на листалку и ваш код?

Comment: > как насчет внести изменения в саму листалку? 
Это не вариант.  
> использовать setTimeout()  
Тоже не катит, нужно мгновенно реагировать, а с этим могут быть большие затраты ресурсов.  
> использования .promise()  
Пытаюсь встроить, пока что без результатов  
> Можно ссылку на листалку  
Вот тут, при смене месяца, всё слитает: http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/doc/

Comment: Я думаю, стоит в дебагере (например хромовском) посмотреть как ведет себя скрипт и уже посмотрев, узнав в чем проблема, пытаться что-то править.

Answer (score 1):

Оберни листалку в div и помести свои элементы непосредственно в него.

Answer (score 0):

Ну создайте какую-нибудь глобальную переменную и в ней сохраняйте.

Comment: Можно пример, не пойму как это?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ было бы написать свою листалку и не мучаться.

А теперь серьёзнее. К сожалению, инструмента, следящего за выполнением пользовательских скриптов, нет, кроме, естественно, дебаггера.

Как вариант, можно отдебажить код листалки, и просто вставить свою функцию в то место, которое обновляет её в самом конце. Тогда не надо следить за ней через `setTimeout()`.

Еще один странный способ отследить Вашу листалку - следить за изменениями в DOM, в любом случае при обновлении выполняется вставка новых/удаление старых элементов. Для этого в "хороших" браузерах существует [MutationObserver()](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutation%20Observer), и его полифиллы, после не очень удачной попытки создать специальные события, это оказалось вполне рабочей штукой. Он позволяет как раз таки узнать, когда произошло ваше изменение. Приведу пример:

Сначала создадим объект `MutationObserver`:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.dir(mutation); //объект с изменениями
        isLastUpdate() && updateListalka(); // если это то самое последнее обновление, то применим Вашу функцию
    });    
});
```

Затем, чтобы эта прелесть заработала, скажем интерпретатору, чтобы "слежение началось":

```
observer.observe(
    listalka,
    {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    }
);
```

Первым аргументом мы передаем объект DOM, за которым нужно следить, вторым то как мы будем следить. В данном случае мы будем следить за вставкой/удалением элементов в `childList` листалки (`childList: true`), а так же за изменениями у всех потомков (`subtree: true`). Если нужно следить еще и за атрибутами, тогда можно написать `attributes: true`. Узнать все параметры можно [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Ну вот, не увидел сразу, что вопрос старый и никому не нужный...

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать jQuery обработчик события [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), который следит за DOM постоянно.

upd: коммент старый, live уже deprecated

Comment: Уточнение. Метод live устарел, привязка живых событий делается через `on`. А вообще, в этом вопросе live не при чём.